# C Preprocessor - Use definitions as integer and as wide strings

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

The version number in my code is defined in a few formats which requires me to change more than one definition when I go up in the version:

```
#define VERSION_N       0x0203
#define SERIALNUMBER_STR    L"2.0.3"
```

and so on.

I'd like to centralize it to one single definition.
Something like:

```
#define VER_X_  0
#define VER_H_  2
#define VER_M_  0
#define VER_L_  3

#define VERSION_N   VER_L_ + 0x10*VER_M_ + 0x100*VER_H_ + 0x1000*VER_X_
#define SERIALNUMBER_STR    ??????????????
```

Comment: You should put parentheses around your macro bodies to prevent surprises due to operator precedence at the expansion site.  i.e. `2*VERSION_N` will give you the wrong result because it will only multiply the `VER_L_` by `2` since `*` has higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: @pat Interesting. Should be put in the final solution though irrelevant in my case. Tx.

Comment: Who started the obsession with trailing underscores in macro names?

Comment: @Shaul the currently accepted answer (written by you) is misleading and even after the edits back in 2014 it is _still_ incorrect.  The other answer by ouah is the best -- please consider accepting that answer instead, to assist future visitors to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the **tested** solution:

```
#define VER_X_  0
#define VER_H_  2
#define VER_M_  0
#define VER_L_  3



#define VERSION_N (VER_L_ + 0x10*VER_M_ + 0x100*VER_H_ + 0x1000*VER_X_)

// Device Strings
//
#define STRINGIFY_1(x)   L#x
#define STRINGIFY(x)     STRINGIFY_1(x)
#define PASTE(x, y) x##y
#define MAKEWIDE(x) PASTE(L,x)

#define SERIALNUMBER_STR MAKEWIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_H_)) L"." \
                         MAKEWIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_M_)) L"." \
                         MAKEWIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_L_))
```

Thanks to ouah

**EDIT:**

1. Added parentheses according to pat.
2. Ouah's remark was taken seriously. Solution adapted to suit MS: Added two PASTE & MAKEWIDE

Comment: see the edit in my answer for wide strings, you should not use `L#x`.

Comment: Just my personal taste, but I find the original two macros **better in any way**. What you ended up with is a lot of obfuscation.

Answer (score 3):

Use a stringify macro:

```
#define STRINGIFY_1(x...)   #x
#define STRINGIFY(x...)     STRINGIFY_1(x)

#define VER_X_  0
#define VER_H_  2
#define VER_M_  0
#define VER_L_  3

#define SERIALNUMBER_STR  STRINGIFY(VER_H_) L"." STRINGIFY(VER_M_)  \
                          L"." STRINGIFY(VER_L_)
```

**EDIT1:** I added the `L` in `L"."` to have wide strings. I don't put a `L#x` as it got expanded with a space and something in the form `L "string"` is not a string literal in C. Nevertheless concatenating a string literal and a wide string literal result in a wide string literal.

**EDIT2:** As put in the comments, the example above work with the last revisions of C (c99 and c11) but not with c89 (i.e., not with MSVC). First reason is variadic macros are not supported in c89. The second reason is in c99 you can concatenate a character string literal and a wide string literal but in c89 this is undefined behavior. Below is a standard solution that also work in c89:

```
#define CAT(x, y)  x##y
#define WIDE(x)    CAT(L,x)

#define STRINGIFY_1(x)   #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)     STRINGIFY_1(x)

#define VER_X_  0
#define VER_H_  2
#define VER_M_  0
#define VER_L_  3

#define SERIALNUMBER_STR  WIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_H_)) L"." WIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_M_))  \
                          L"." WIDE(STRINGIFY(VER_L_))
```

Comment: Not compiling.
Perhaps not supported by MS (I'm using Build 6.0) 
Also, I need a **wide** char string.

Comment: @Shaul MSVC does not support c99, remove the `...` in the macro and it will work with MSVC.

Comment: MS did not accept the change. Error message is: error C2308: concatenating mismatched strings.

Comment: @Shaul another c89 issue. Concatenating wide string literal and character string literal is OK in c99 (and the result is a wide string literal) but is undefined behavior in c89.